# Do I need to check data integrity after sending file over ftp?

Tags: integrity, tcp, ftp, sftp

I need to transfer some files from remote computer (on local network) and I plan to do it via FTP.

Apparently, FTP is based on TCP protocol and if I remember well my lessons the difference between TCP and UDP is that TCP checks that network packets are correctly send and received.

After asking myself if I need to add checksum verification, my conclusion was that **I don't need to**. Am I correct ?

I'm aware of the differences between binary transfer and text transfer and plan to do only binary transfers (working only on Windows).

Do I really need to checksum big files transfered by binary FTP ?

Be it clear, I need data integrity to verify that some bits where not altered during the exchange. Man in the middle is not (much) an issue because the operation will be done in a private network.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a security question. Unless you had a security angle to it?

Comment: Would you consider using SFTP instead? That would defeat the MITM aspect.

Comment: you don't NEED to, but you might WANT to when you care about integrity

Comment: @schroeder : Data integrity is a security matter. Imagine bank operation transit and suddenly a bit appeared and 10$ becomes 100$...

Comment: In broad terms, sure. But this is a pure "checksum" question, which makes this more of a programming question.

Comment: The TCP checksum is not a security checksum. If someone tampers with the traffic, they can easily generate checksums that match the tampered traffic. SFTP uses security checksums as well as encryption.

Comment: @schroeder : would using SFTP or FTPS garanty a higher bit error detection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do.

A man in the middle can alter any TCP packets on the way from the ftp server to your site or he can even act as a malicious ftp site and suppress the original traffic completely.

Therefore you need to verify somehow that that file you received is really the file you wanted to receive. Checksums are suitable for this task.

Comment: But then how would I communicate the checksum ? Via another protocol ?

Comment: @Kil: Yes, of course, via another protocol. E.g. Apache has download pages accessible via https (a secure protocol), but uses ftp for fast and efficient software distribution.

Comment: @jknappen FTP is neither fast nor efficient for transmitting files. I have no idea why it is still so widely used for software distribution...

Comment: @jknappen : what if there's a deamon scanning when a file is shared via FTP and processing datas in it automatically. I need this to be automated.

Comment: You can automate checksum checking as well. Alternatively, since you control both ends of the chain, you can sign the file you transfer with a cryptographic signature and check this.